# Removing extra spaces from string when it contains a \ character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a string in this form:

```py
my_string = "select \\\"ASSETS\\\" AS \\\"LEASE_ASSETS\\\", count(*) CNT FROM \\\"SIY\\\".\\\"I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT\\\" group by \\\"ASSETS\\\" order by \\\"ASSETS\\\""
```

I want to remove these `\\\`, but I am not sure if `str.replace()` is a good option.

The main thing I want is to get this `Table` name part from it, like this:

```
"SIY.I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT"
```

... which, due to those spaces, I am not able to get. I want to do it by using `str.replace()`, but it seems both are not working.

Comment: this seems like it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .. where did you get the original string from? to just remove them all, you can just replace the backslash (used as an escape character) with `""`

Comment: @ti7 there is a object and in a key I am getting this . these will come in same way always . and can you please tell a little in detail about solution please with exampl,e ?

Comment: Don't confuse the string with a particular string *literal*. `my_string = 'select \\"ASSETS\\" ...'` would work the same, and in neither case does your string contain consecutive backslashes.

Comment: @chepner  why this \\\ convert into this \\ ? not getting this thing

Comment: It doesn't. ``\\`` is a literal backslash, while `\"` is a literal `"`; ergo, `\\\"` is `\"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If query will be the same then you filter un wanted things one by one then extract your required words

```
my_string = "select \\\"ASSETS\\\" AS \\\"LEASE_ASSETS\\\", count(*) CNT FROM \\\"SIY\\\".\\\"I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT\\\" group by \\\"ASSETS\\\" order by \\\"ASSETS\\\""
my_string= my_string.replace("\\", '').replace('"', '')
print (my_string[my_string.find('FROM ')+len('FROM '):my_string.rfind('group')])
```

Gives #

```
SIY.I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT
```

Comment: Why are you importing `re`, since your answer is not using it?

Comment: Just tried `re.sub` before before `str.replace`.. forget to remove it

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better methods, but I'd turn it into a list and append through that removing any slashes. You can rejoin this string using the .join function afterward.

```
my_list = list(my_string)
for i in range(len(my_list)):
     if my_list[i] == "/":
          my_list[i] = ""
my_string = ''.join(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, watch out, there's some difference between how string escape characters are *represented* and how they're *displayed*

```py
>>> my_string = "select \\\"ASSETS\\\" AS \\\"LEASE_ASSETS\\\", count(*) CNT FROM \\\"SIY\\\".\\\"I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT\\\" group by \\\"ASSETS\\\" order by \\\"ASSETS\\\""
>>> my_string
'select \\"ASSETS\\" AS \\"LEASE_ASSETS\\", count(*) CNT FROM \\"SIY\\".\\"I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT\\" group by \\"ASSETS\\" order by \\"ASSETS\\"'
>>> print(my_string)
select \"ASSETS\" AS \"LEASE_ASSETS\", count(*) CNT FROM \"SIY\".\"I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT\" group by \"ASSETS\" order by \"ASSETS\"
```

However, you can directly use the `.replace()` method on the string to get rid of these

```py
>>> my_string.replace("\\", "")
'select "ASSETS" AS "LEASE_ASSETS", count(*) CNT FROM "SIY"."I7_MAIN_ACCOUNT" group by "ASSETS" order by "ASSETS"'
```